# Search function not working in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a search box that will return all the listings in my database that have the same tag as what the user wrote in the search bar, but for some reason, when I go to the new intent, the list just stays the same, showing every listing that I have in the database. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.shareandcare;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class listings extends Activity {

    private Cursor c = null;
    private listingHelperAdapter adapter = new listingHelperAdapter(c);
    private listingHelper helper = new listingHelper(this);
    private ListView list;
    private Button listingsAddListingButton, listingsSearchButton;
    private AutoCompleteTextView listingsSearch;
    private TextView empty = null;
    private String searchStr = null;

    private static final String[] TAGS = new String[] {
            "Sofa", "Table", "Bed", "Storage", "Tool"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listings);

        empty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listings_Empty);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listings_List);

        listingsAddListingButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.listings_Add_Listing_Button);
        listingsSearchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.listings_Search_Button);
        listingsSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.listings_Search);
        c = helper.getAll();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TAGS);
        listingsSearch.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listingsSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listingsSearch.getText().toString() != "") {
                    searchStr = listingsSearch.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listings.this, listings.class);
                    intent.putExtra("search", searchStr);
                    helper.setSearchStat(true);
                    //finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (listingsSearch.getText().toString() == null){
                    helper.setSearchStat(false);
                }
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                helper.delete(String.valueOf(l));
                //helper.resetDatabase();
                Toast.makeText(listings.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(listings.this, listings.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                c.moveToPosition(i);
                String title = helper.getListingTitle(c);
                Intent intent = new Intent(listings.this, listing.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",title);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listingsAddListingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(listings.this, addListing.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
        if (helper.getSearchStat() == false) {
            c = helper.getAll();
        } else if (helper.getSearchStat() == true) {
            c = helper.getByTag(getIntent().getStringExtra("search"));
        }


        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        adapter.swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        helper.close();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){

        if (item.getItemId()== R.id.log_out) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(listings.this, mainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    class listingHelperAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        listingHelperAdapter(Cursor c) {
            super(listings.this, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
            listingHolder holder = (listingHolder) row.getTag();

            holder.populate(c, helper);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listingrow, parent, false);
            listingHolder holder = new listingHolder(row);

            row.setTag(holder);
            return (row);
        }
    }

    static class listingHolder {
        private TextView listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription;
        //private ImageView furnitureImage = null;

        listingHolder (View row){
            listingTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listing_Title);
            listingTag = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listing_Tag);
            listingDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listing_Description);
        }

        void populate (Cursor c,listingHelper helper){
            listingTitle.setText(helper.getListingTitle(c));
            listingTag.setText(helper.getListingTag(c));
            listingDescription.setText(helper.getListingDesciption(c));
        }
    }
}
```

And if it helps, here is my database helper as well:

```
package com.example.shareandcare;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class listingHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private boolean x = false;

    public listingHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "listing.db", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table listing(_id integer primary key autoincrement, listingTitle text, listingTag text, listingDescription text, listingDimensionX float, listingDimensionY float, listingDimensionZ float, listingImage text, listingStatus text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists listing");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing order by listingTag", null));
    }

    public Cursor getAllConfirmed() {
        String arg = "1";
        String[] args = {arg};
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingStatus=?", args));
    }

    public Cursor getById(String id) {
        String[] args = {id};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, lisitngDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where _id=?", args));
    }

    public Cursor getByTitle(String title) {
        String[] args = {title};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingTitle =?", args));
    }

    public Cursor getByTag(String tag) {
        tag = tag.toLowerCase();
        String[] args = {tag};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingTag =?", args));
    }

    public void setSearchStat(boolean status) {
        x = status;
    }

    public boolean getSearchStat() {
        return x;
    }

    public void updateListingStatus(String title) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        String[] args ={title};

        cv.put("listingStatus", "1");
        getWritableDatabase().update("listing", cv, "listingTitle=?", args);
    }

    public void addListing(String listingTitle, String listingTag, String listingDescription, String listingDimensionX, String listingDimensionY, String listingDimensionZ, String listingImage) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("listingTitle", listingTitle);
        cv.put("listingTag", listingTag.toLowerCase());
        cv.put("listingDescription", listingDescription);
        cv.put("listingDimensionX", listingDimensionX);
        cv.put("listingDimensionY", listingDimensionY);
        cv.put("listingDimensionZ", listingDimensionZ);
        cv.put("listingImage", listingImage);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("listing", "listingTitle", cv);
    }

    public void delete(String id) {
        String[] args = {id};
        getWritableDatabase().delete("listing","_id=?", args);
    }

    public String getID(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(0));
    }

    public String getListingTitle (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(1));
    }

    public String getListingTag (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(2));
    }

    public String getListingDesciption (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(3));
    }

    public String getListingDimensionX (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(4));
    }

    public String getListingDimensionY (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(5));
    }

    public String getListingDimensionZ (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(6));
    }

    public String getListingImage (Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(7));
    }

    public void resetDatabase() {
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL("drop table if exists listing");
    }
}
```